Why USB external drives are sometimes randomly not detected?
I have noticed that sometimes an external USB storage (USB stick, USB HDD, USB SSD) is not recognized in one USB port, no matter how many times I plug it in that port, it wont work. If I connect it into another USB port, then it works fine. This is completely random in the sense that maybe the next day, the same device works fine in any port, and then the next week this happens again with some port, but then the day after it works, and so. I've been using Ubuntu (and Xubuntu and Lubuntu) on a daily basis in my personal and work PCs since 2012, and I have experienced this issue with tenths of USB storage devices over the years. I am sure I am not the only one experiencing this, and I am curious about what is the reason. For sure it cannot be any kind of software thing because I have had USB storage devices for many years using them on the same PC with the same Ubuntu installation for years, and randomly some days they just don't work on one of the ports but they do on the others, and the next day this is fixed.

I would say this is a Hardware Issue with your computer and potentially a dying USB controller.  Unfortunately, there's no way to really debug hardware issues like this in Ubuntu, especially if it's "random" that this happens.  I would suggest that if your system is old you start looking into a new system, because hardware does wear out after a while

Forgot to mention that this has happened to me with at least 4 different PCs over the years... Right now I have a quite new Lenovo ThinkPad.

are you sure it is fully unmounted. Writes may say done, but I see flash drive flickering for quite a while as it finishes writing. And if NTFS, Windows updates like to turn fast startup back on, preventing full mounting of NTFS partitions. Does it work after reboot?

I mean, normally you connect it and it shows up in the file explorer app. You click and it mounts it. When this thing happens, it does not show up there, until I connect it into a different port. Then it works perfectly.

I too have seen this with USB sticks on a dell 7020 running xubuntu 22.04.

My motivation to write this question was that yesterday I got a brand new Samsung T7 storage and it would not work in any of the USB C ports of my PC (this means, I connect it and it does not show up in the file explorer to "click'n mount"). Fine, I used it in the regular USB ports. Today, having done nothing, it is right now working in the USB C port...
